# How should one interpret the odds ration estimate for a numeric independent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I am calculating odds ratios for a logistic regression, where the first dependent variable is a dummy and the second one is numeric.
If the interpretation of the first coefficient is straightforward, how should I interpret the second one?

````
function <- y ~ x1 + x2
logitor(function, data, robust = TRUE, clustervar1 = NULL, clustervar2 = NULL, start = NULL)

Call:
logitor(formula = mod_0, data = data, robust = TRUE, clustervar1 = NULL, 
    clustervar2 = NULL, start = NULL)

Odds Ratio:
              OddsRatio      Std. Err.       z      P>|z|    
x1            0.999926731792 0.000008632814 -8.4869 0.000220 ***
x2            1.002100923867 0.000556887005  3.7766 0.000159 ***


```
````

Comment: @TrungDung Isn't the 1.0021 already exponentiated, so $\exp(.0021) = 1.0021$?

Comment: I did not notice the column names. Yes, the name is OddsRatio, I have edited.

Comment: EDIT: Similar to simple linear regression model, controlling for $x_1$, when $x_2$ increases one unit, the odds changes 1.0021 times.